# The position of SVG is off on Chrome. How do I align it to how it is displayed on Firefox?

Tags: html, css, svg

I don't know why this is happening.  Ideally, I would like the svg to be displayed over the text on all browsers, but Chrome is not making this happen.   This is how it looks like on Firefox:
[image: Firefox svg]

And this is how it looks like on Chrome: 
[image: Chrome svg issue]
As you can tell, the svg is on the text.  I don't know if it's the margin or the svg but I would like to understand how I can fix this.

Here is my CSS:

```
svg{
        display:block;
}
#rect{
    margin-top:-150px; /*helps svg display over text on Firefox. Nothing happens on Chrome*/
    margin-left:200px;
    height:500px;
}
```

And this is the SVG code:

```
 <div class="circle-border">
          <div class="svg">

        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 19.0.1, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
        <svg id="rect"  version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
        viewBox="0 0 960 560"  xml:space="preserve">
        <style type="text/css">
        .st0{fill:none;stroke:white;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
        </style>
        <polygon class="st0" points="224.5,150.5 224.5,477.5 649.5,477.5 649.5,444.5 682.5,444.5 682.5,412.5 715.5,412.5 715.5,379.5 
        748.5,379.5 748.5,346.5 780.5,346.5 780.5,150.5 "/>
      </svg>

    </div><!--border-->
```

Feel free to let me know if you need additional information.

Comment: They render identically for me on a test page http://jsfiddle.net/1b1o1erz/ So there must be something else going on in your page to cause it.  Unfortunately there is not enough information here to diagnose the problem.  You should put up a sample somewhere showing the fault in action.

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks for your response.  I am sort of new.  Mind if I ask how I can go about showing the fault in action? And also, the code is inside the Foundation Framework.

Comment: Use jsfiddle.net or use the [code snippet feature of StackOverlow](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  Include just enough of your HTML to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Wow! I never knew StackOverflow had this feature. And I realized that from research display:block is kinda iffy on the Chrome browser.  To fix this, I replaced it with position:absolute under #rect.

Comment: @user2843235 display:block is NOT 'iffy' in Chrome. The markup you show might be invalid.

Comment: In fact, it is invalid.

Comment: I double checked on my HTML markup and I didn't spot any invalid markup such as missing divs, etc.  I even have <!DOC html> before my html tag.